# Drawing large array of images to html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm getting a problem with loading a large array of images to a html canvas element. Basically what I'm trying to do is getting a small part of every image in the array (1px w,256px h) and composing a new picture on the canvas with all these smaller images.

When I'm running this code, I'm getting all images on the screen printed. However, when I run it using the for loop, the image stays white.

```
function addToCanvas()
{   
    drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawingCanvas');
    context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        //for(imgNo=0;imgNo<256;imgNo++){
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, 1, 256, 0+(imgNo), 0, 1, 256);
        }
        imgObj.src = imgs[imgNo];
        imgNo++;    
        //}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a closure problem, not related to canvas. When the loop is in place, you are creating a closure around the `imgNo` variable, not its value. So when those event handlers finally fire, chances are very good the loop has finished and `imgNo` is equal to 256 for all of them.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
function addToCanvas()
{   
    drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawingCanvas');
    context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
        for(imgNo=0;imgNo<256;imgNo++){
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.onload = (function(i) {
            return function () {
            context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, 1, 256, 0+(i), 0, 1, 256);
            }
        })(imgNo);

        imgObj.src = imgs[imgNo];
        imgNo++;    
    }
}
```

I am creating an anonymous function that returns a function, it returns the event handler. Then immediately calling it with imgNo's current value. This causes it to capture its current value in a new variable, and pass that new variable on to the event handler.

Comment: Thanks! It's (almost) working. I'm reading about closures and for loops in JavaScript now, hope I'm going to find the solution. But the problem I'm encountering now is that the code doesn't print the next picture to the screen. It's copying the data from the first 1x256 px. (see http://imageupload.org/?d=4DA6AD391 and http://imageupload.org/?d=4DA6AD3A1)